# Does offhand sigil actives activate while using skills from my main hand?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I think the easiest way to explain what I mean is by giving you a scenario.

Suppose I am dual wielding two one-handed weapons. In my main hand I have a sword with a sigil of blood which has a chance of stealing health. In my offhand I have an axe with a sigil of air which has a chance of causing a lightning strike.

Will the active proc of stealing life from the sword proc only when I am using the first three skills from my sword or will it also proc for the skills from my axe?

Will the lightning strike active from my offhand axe proc while I am using the spammable first skill from the sword or does it only proc when I use my two last skills from the axe offhand?

Comment: I was just wondering this myself last night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From playing with a dual dagger elementalist, <strike>I believe that sigils which proc 'on critical hit' are tied to the weapons skills, so you're correct in assuming that the life stealing will only proc when using the first three skills.</strike>

Correction: According to this thread: http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/43566-weapon-sigil-questions/ Critical Hit sigils should fire regardless on the skill used, even utility skills, so as long as the weapon is equipped, the effects should be active.

I haven't used the 'on critical hit' sigils too much, as I tend to rely on the 'on weapon swap' sigils, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Just to expand this answer. Swapping attunements for Elementalist counts as a weapon swap for '..on weapon swap' sigils, as per, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PKPbboLqzM#t=11m33s

Comment: What about applied condition duration increases? I.e., Burning or vulnerabiliy +10%?

Comment: I imagine they function the same way, and they apply whenever you apply the condition on a foe, regardless of weapon or utility skill.